# SQL function to split a string into characters

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I hava an ID column in my database, and it shows the results as follows

- 1121
- 1232
- 1233

and i want to get an extra column where i can have their sums as follows

- 5
- 8
- 9

can anyone help me which sql function should i use to break a string into characters and add them?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I split a string so I can access item x](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2647/how-do-i-split-a-string-so-i-can-access-item-x)

Comment: Is ID always 4 digits only?

Comment: Is the id always a number?

Comment: @shree.pat18 yes it always is 4 digits long.

Comment: @ocasoProtal i checked it too, doesn't solve my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming a number that is always 4 digits long, you can simply do this:

```
select (id/1000)+((id%1000)/100)+((id%100)/10)+(id%10)
```

If the ID field is `varchar`, just cast it to an `int` before division. Of course, if the result of this has more than 1 digit, you will not be able to get the sum of its digits again.

Answer (score 1):

You could use this [table-valued function](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191165(v=sql.105).aspx):

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[Chars]
(
    @Text NVARCHAR(MAX)
)
RETURNS @ItemTable TABLE (Item VARCHAR(250))  
AS      

BEGIN    
    DECLARE @i INT    
    DECLARE @Item NVARCHAR(4000)

    SET @i = 1

    WHILE (@i <= LEN(@Text))
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO @ItemTable(Item) 
        VALUES(SUBSTRING(@Text, @i, 1))
        SET @i = @i + 1
    END 
    RETURN
END
```

Now this query should work as desired:

```
SELECT t.ID, SUM(CAST(Split.Item AS INT)) AS SumID
FROM dbo.TableName t
CROSS APPLY dbo.Chars(CONVERT(varchar(10), t.ID))Split
GROUP BY t.ID
```

Here's a **demo**: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/8eea7/8/0

Comment: +1 for the dynamic approach. IT works for more than 4 digits too.